# Two Stack Overflow Podcast on iTunes. Is either "official?"

Tags: support, podcast

While subscribing to the Stack Overflow podcasts on iTunes, I noticed there were *two* entries to subscribe to:

- Blog - Stack Overflow
- Stack Overflow

They are currently being updated with the same content but I'm subscribed to both because I don't want to miss anything if one suddenly stops being updated.

Is one more "official" than the other?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that one is from [blog.stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) and the other is from [IT Conversations](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/) which is used to host the podcast files. The content should be identical, but the ITC version sometimes arrives earlier than the blog.stackoverflow.com post IME.

Comment: You're right, they are from different places but equally official.

Comment: I have both RSS feeds in my feed reader, and the ITC one always comes out before the other one. The one from the blog has more information in the feed though.